# Flask-migrate and Flask-script setting up Procfile for heroku?

Tags: heroku, flask, procfile, flask-migrate

I am using flask-migrate and flask-script to init the database and run migrations.

For the most part I use the flask-script example on the flask-migrate website and run commands like `python manage.py db init`.

My question is how do add this to my procfile for heroku deployment?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to install [The Heroku Command Line Interface](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) (CLI), then run this command on your computer, just like this:

```
$ heroku login
$ heroku run python manage.py db init
```